Long running program started from cron
Is there a problem to start long running program from cron? Long running means that it has to run all time without interruption but in case it is closed, cron will restart it again. I don't know whether cron will wait the job to finish. The idea is to start a program e.g. every 5 minutes. The program will lock a file and next instance will close itself immediately. If running program exists for some reason (error), the file lock is released and cron will restart it up to 5 min. The alternative is to use a loop in bash script which restarts the program but I prefer cron method if it is viable.

Your method would work assuming the locking is done well. As an alternative, have you considered using systemd to manage the server with an automatic restart if/when the service exits?
